# how to remove the spaces after the Dots in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[these both names are same but extra spaces differentiate them .using trim function removed these spaces of these names .but I want a function to remove space after Dot symbol for all the name in the column 'Author' ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwqGY.jpg)

Comment: PLease write and type your question and copy-paste data to include it here. See [tour] and [MRE]

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.replace`:

```
>>> df
          Author
0  J. K. Rowling
```

```
df['Author'] = df['Author'].str.replace(r'\.\s+', '.')
print(df)

# Output
        Author
0  J.K.Rowling
```